# Bit fields portability in a shared library

Tags: c, portability, bit-fields, cc

I have difficulty to understand the portability of bit fields in C. Imagine I have a shared library composed of only two files, `libfoobar.h` (the public header) and `libfoobar.c`, with the following simple content:

`libfoobar.h`:

```c
typedef struct some_bitfield_T {
    unsigned char foo:3;
    unsigned char bar:2;
    unsigned char tree:2;
    unsigned char window:1;
} some_bitfield;

extern unsigned int some_function (some_bitfield input);
```

`libfoobar.c`:

```c
#include "libfoobar.h"

unsigned int some_function (some_bitfield input) {
    return input.foo * 3 + input.bar + input.tree + 1 - input.window;
}
```

After having compiled and installed the library, I test it with a program named `test`.

`test.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libfoobar.h>

int main () {
    some_bitfield my_attempt = {
        .foo = 6,
        .bar = 3,
        .tree = 1,
        .window = 1
    };
    unsigned int some_number = some_function(my_attempt);
    printf("Here is the result: %u\n", some_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any possibility that the `test` program above will produce anything different than the following output?

```
Here is the result: 22
```

If yes, when? What if the library is compiled by someone else other than me? What if I use different compilers for the library and the `test` program?

Comment: Bit-fields are generally not portable. Compilers are allowed to reorder members, and there's nothing specified about possible padding in the structure.

Comment: But does that not apply also to normal structures?

Comment: Padding yes, so structures used in shared libraries needs to be very carefully designed to not have any padding between members. But for normal structures, members can *not* be rearranged, unlike bit-fields.

Comment: But why would a compiler want to reorder members within a byte?

Comment: Tom, if it is true that a compiler can re-order members as they say, it might not show 22 everywhere.

Comment: Tom, if I understood well, if the compiler that compiled the library chose to put `foo` first, it will produce assembly code equivalent to `input & 7` for `input.foo` in the return value of `some_function()`. But if the compiler that compiled `test.c` chose instead to put `foo` as the last member, it will call `some_function()` using `(my_attempt.foo << 5) & 255` for the value of `input`.

Comment: @TheWebIsTheOldBlack I think I misunderstood your question.  It sounds like you're concerned that a library may have been built incompatibly from the code that uses it.  I suppose that's a risk.  If a library uses one type of packing, and the code that uses it uses a different packing, then yes, you would have problems.  If that's a genuine concern, then your best bet is to probably avoid the use of bit fields.

Comment: @TheWebIsTheOldBlack Also, when replying to someone specific in a comment, use @ in front of their name so it will appear in their inbox.  Otherwise they might not notice it.

Comment: @TomKarzes That's a horrible situation for C bit fields. I still don't understand why a compiler would want to order the fields within a byte. Doesn't endianness concern the order of bytes (not bits)?

Comment: @TheWebIsTheOldBlack I believe bit fields are typically packed left-to-right on big-endian machines and right-to-left on little-endian machines, but I don't think it's guaranteed.  If you know your library was built with the same compiler, or with a compiler that uses the same packing, then you might assume they're compatible.  But I don't usually see bit fields in library interfaces.  More often they're internal to an application in which all files are compiled the same way, so it's not an issue in that case.

Comment: `why a compiler would want to order the fields within a byte` Because some people think about bytes starting from MSB others start from LSB, so some compilers start with LSB and others with MSB. Note that endianess (order of bytes within words) is not the order of bits in bytes.

Comment: @KamilCuk But that's the point: why should endianness influence my single byte?

Comment: Because compiler writers decide so. They can, it's implementation defined, so they do. And endianess does _not_ influence order of bits in byte. It's separate setting. Ex. [gcc has](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Storage-Layout.html) `BITS_BIG_ENDIAN` and `BYTES_BIG_ENDIAN` (configure flags) separately.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you. I did not know about the [BITS_BIG_ENDIAN](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Storage-Layout.html) macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitfields are implementation defined and not not portable.  But for most relevant platforms, their extraction/packing is well specified by the ABI so that they can be safely used in shared libraries.

E.g.:

- [ARM EABI](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/resources/eecs373/ARM-AAPCS-EABI-v2.08.pdf) specifies them in 7.1.7 "Bit-fields".
- [i386 ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) specifies them on page 3-6+
- [x86-64](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) specifies them on page 15+
- [MIPS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/mipsabi.pdf) specifies them on page 3-7+

Comment: Thank you, ensc. Are you saying that my library would always work in practice?

Comment: Also the question is: Imagine that my library gets distributed in binary form for a specific platform, let's say Linux x86-64. Is it possible that the programs that use it won't work properly?

Comment: @TheWebIsTheOldBlack practically mo (they are compatible) and compilers try to have the same behavior.  Nevertheless I would be carefully with exotic features (volatile bitfields, explicit alignment) because there might be compiler bugs on non-major platforms due to blurriness in  their ABI specfication.

Comment: Thank you, ensc. I think using plain bit-fields without exotic qualifiers should be pretty portable then.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the relevant section of the C11 standard:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

§6.7.2.1 point 11.

This means that the compiler can use any suitable type it likes to hold the bitfields and that they will be adjacent to each and in the order they were defined.

However, the compiler can choose for itself whether to order them from high to low or from low to high. It can also choose to overlap bitfields if it run out of space or to allocate a new storage unit (not a problem in your case, you only have 8 bits).

With the above in mind, we can answer your question. You can *only* guarantee that your test program will give the right answer if the program and the library were compiled with the *same* compiler implementation. If you use two different compilers, even if they both use (say) `unsigned char` to store the bit fields in, one could start from the top of the byte and the other could start from the bottom.

In practice, as  ensc says above, a platform ABI might define a bit field packing and ordering standard, that makes it OK between compilers on the same platform, but this is not guaranteed in principle.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. This is the situation from the perspective of the C standard. But if I understood ensc's answer well, bitfields seem to be guaranteed to have always the same order within the same ABI. So if my library is compiled, let's say, for a x86-64 machine, it should always work independently of the compilers I choose. Or am I missing something?

Comment: For example, I read in the [x86-64 ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf): "... Bit-fields obey the same size and alignment rules as other structure and union members. Also: bit-fields are allocated from right to left ...". This makes bitfields virtually always portable, as programs compiled for different ABIs won't be linkable anyway.

Comment: @TheWebIsTheOldBlack yes, assuming the compiler adheres to the ABI in every aspect, which is more than likely once almost everybody uses clang or gcc nowadays. Personally, I don't really see the point of bit fields and I never use them.

Comment: That is fantastic to know! When they say that the order of bit-fields is implementation-defined they forget to say that _it is defined somewhere_... The ABI! The fact that the C standard doesn't define them does not mean that nobody else does. If you have two dozens of booleans to send to a library bitfields are really the most practical option. We could use bitmasks, but they would be incredibly verbose.

Answer (score 1):

> I have difficulty to understand the portability of bit fields in C

Well, there's nothing much understand - bitfields are not portable.

> Is there any possibility that the test program above will produce anything different than the following output?

The most common case is communication between user space and kernel space. Sometimes the communication uses pointers to structures. Headers written by library implementators, like `glibc`, that wrap kernel syscalls sometimes duplicate the same structures that are defined inside kernel source tree. For proper communication, the padding in those structures must be the same on both sides - on the kernel side when kernel is compiled and on user space side when we happy compile our own project even years after kernel was compiled.

On most architectures + operating systems there exists a "ABI" - a set of rules that also determine how structures should be padded and how bit-fields should be packed. A compiler *may* adhere to that ABI or not. When gcc is used to cross-compile for windows from linux, ex.  `__attribute__ ((ms_struct))` needs be used to ensure that proper structure packing is used that is compatible with the shenanigans microsoft compilers do.

So to answer: `Is there any possibility` - sure there is, different compiler flags or settings may cause different packing or padding between structure members So I can compile the program with `gcc -fpack-struct=100` and you compiled your shared library with `gcc -fpack-struct=20` and oops. But this isn't limited to structure padding - someone else can compile your program with `unsigned int` having 64-bits instead of 32-bit, so the return value of the function may be unexpected.

> If yes, when?

When incompatible code generation methods are used to create machine code that depend on specified ABI to communicate. From the practical side, does this ever happen? Each linux system has *ton* of shared libraries in `/usr/lib`.

> What if the library is compiled by someone else other than me?

Then he can do whatever he wants. But you can communicate that your shared library follows some common ABI standard, if you really want to.

> What if I use different compilers for the library and the test program?

Then be sure to read that compiler documentation to make sure it follows the common ABI that you need.

Read: [How to Write Shared Libraries. Ulrich Drepper](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) - section 3 seems to be related.

Comment: Thank you, KamilCuk. Somehow this makes the bit-field situation looks less tragic. If I understood the situation well, if I compile my library using gcc for Linux without specifying any exotic compiler option, I expect that a good compiler like gcc will simply obey to the ABI. Therefore my library's binary will be quite compatible _unless your program doesn't follow the ABI_. Did I get it right?

Comment: Generally yes. Still, don't. Until standard committee makes bitfields portable, the general advise is: do not use them. But I see many bitfields in my `grep -r ' *: *[0-9]\+;' /usr/include` tree.

Comment: I see them too in my `/usr/include` tree. The fear of bit-fields looks to me a bit like the fear of `goto` statements. I think we should stop saying that bit-fields are not portable. They definitely are. Also the size of an `int` is implementation-defined, but an `int` is portable and its size _is defined somewhere_ – just not the C Standard. It is exactly the same situation. Between us an the C Standard there are several layers of intermediate committees and standardizations, most notably the common ABI, that do define pretty much everything.

Comment: Puff, you are mentioning portability of code between compilers. That's the easy case, covered by ABI. The problem is portability between _architectures_, when you expect same order of bitfields on different architectures (on different ABIs). This is the problem. Bitfields were created by the prophet to alias hardware location, yet because they are not portable, they can't be used for that. The typical example is (was?) TCP/IP layer in kernel - I remember it used bitfields a lot and did a lot of work to pack them the same on any endianess.

Comment: I guess that would be the case of using a `union` for accessing the raw content of a bit-field? If yes I don't care about that. I just want that bit-fields are always portable when used properly, that is when they are used for what they are: bit-fields, to be accessed using their names.

Comment: If you do not ever expect the bitfield to be at specified memory location, ie. you'll like never expect `some_bitfield::bar` to start at bit 4 LSB at first byte of the structure, then it is as portable as mentioned `int` having some size - so portable. If you do, however expect that setting some bitfield will flip _specific_ bit in a _specific_ byte - then this expectancy is not portable (ex. because ABI is different between architectures and OSes, etc). So if you care only about value, sure. Then you might as well not use bitfields at all.

Comment: As I said, I only want to read `some_bitfield::foo` and expect that the program that uses my library does not pass me `some_bitfield::tree` and `some_bitfield::window` merged together instead.